# JUnit to connect to Oracle DB from Jenkins

Tags: database, jenkins, junit

I would like to connect to the actual physical database from JUnit, while it runs from Jenkins during maven build/test. I am using JBoss for writing JUnit. I don't want to store the DB connection string within the JUnit code/git/svn. I will rather externalize it either via a datasource and connect using JNDI in runtime or any other mechanism. Is there a way, I can use the datasource setup in Jenkins to connect to DB or Is there a better approach to achieve this? Basically, I want to hide the connection id/pwd for the developers as well, so they don't know/see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables or system properties to provide configuration from Jenkins to a JUnit test. Read them in your test and use it to establish a connection to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

But those will be readable ad the developers have access to the Jenkins job configuration.